# Magento : Change Stock Availability From Dropdown to Text

Tags: magento-1.9, product, stock, stock-status

I want to change Stock Availability of product in backend, from drop down to text area to add custom text for product. My version is Magento 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I made an attribute called "customstock"
Then in `public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default,phtml`
I changed the code to

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $_product->getData('customstock'); ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```